# Convert array of objects to another array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to convert array of objects to just objects to use it in table datasource:

```
{v_report_full: Array(25)}
v_report_full: Array(25)
0:
first_name: "Blake"
last_name: "Thorphan"
middle_name: "Agder"
monh: "2021-02-01 00:00:00"
n_vh: "Delay 00:04:52"
n_vh_s_obeda: "ok"
n_vyh: "ok"
n_vyh_s_obeda: "ok"
name: "oitib"
rtime: null
vh_s_obeda_ts: null
vhod_ts: "2021-02-01 08:59:52"
vyh_s_obeda_ts: null
vyhod_ts: null
__typename: "Ereport"
__proto__: Object
1:.. the same next index
2:.. the same next index
```

Table datasource requires next order:

```
const dataSource = [
  {
    key: '1',
    name: 'Mike',
    age: 32,
    address: '10 Downing Street',
  },
  {
    key: '2',
    name: 'John',
    age: 42,
    address: '10 Downing Street',
  },
];
```

I've tried to use Object.keys, but have not enough expirience to do that. If here is a simple solution, if not I have to write a loop for each row with function to concat, etc?

Upd. These one was I worked with:

```
let dataSource = (data) ? data.v_report_full.map((value, index, array) => {
        return {
            
            id: value.id,
            key: value.id,
            
            first_name:(value, 'first_name'),
            .....
}
```

After hatfield advise, I checked once more and it's working! A liitle changes and above code then working now D: What a noob I am.

Comment: Have you considered [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)?

Comment: datasource must have 25 items as well? The question isn't clear.

Comment: Thanks all, after advise of hatfield I checked once more and it's working!